# Is it possible to import Tasks from a spreadsheet/csv file into JIRA Agile (Greenhopper)?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

In TFS online it is possible to import spread-sheet data to populate Stories / Tasks.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible in JIRA and if so give guidance on achieving this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the JIRA CSV importer (as a JIRA admin) and import the data. Then define the board's filter to include the imported issues